# QuillJS won't setContent from api

Tags: javascript, quill

I am trying to set the contents of my editor from my api call (using an ajax request), however, it won't update the editor.  I'm not sure why because when I do

```
alert(data.content) -- it returns {"ops":[{"insert":"Test 123\n"}]}
```

and

```
quill.setContents({"ops":[{"insert":"Test 123\n"}]}, 'api');
```

works as expected, however, nothing happens when I do

```
quill.setContents(data.content, 'api')
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[setContents from APi](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBpXEW) is working.

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});

var ops = [
  { insert: 'Hello ' },
  { insert: 'World!', attributes: { bold: true } },
  { insert: '\n' }
];
quill.setContents(ops, 'api');
```

You are probably passing a string instead of an object.

Try calling JSON.parse(data.content) to convert the string to an object.

Comment: You are right, I needed to add JSON.parse(data.content).  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Try calling JSON.parse(data.content) to convert the string to an object.
It saved my day. Bundle of thanks @Ben Browitt